# Difference in Tcl script execution with and without "-f"

Tags: bash, tcl, tclsh

I have a tcl script file called `hello.tcl`, with the following content:

```
puts "hello world"
```

When  I run it on bash using the command,

```
tclsh hello.tcl
```

I get the hello print.

However, if I use `tclsh -f` instead of just `tclsh` above, I don't get any print, only the tcl prompt. Why don't I get any prints in the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tclsh` syntax is:

```
tclsh ?-encoding name? ?fileName arg arg ...?
```

That means you can call it like this:

```
tclsh hell.tcl
tclsh -encoding (something) hell.tcl
```

Anything else is an error. Instead of barking at you, `tclsh` silently ignores the error and open up the shell.

## Tcl Command Notation

I found Tcl command notation a bit strange at first, and could not find any reference any where. However, here are what I understand:

- The `? ... ?` notation means optional
- Tcl commands use a single dash as opposed to double dash: `-encoding` instead of '--encoding`

## Manual

As for help, I installed ActiveState Tcl 8.5 and it comes with a file called *ActiveTclHelp8.5.chm*, which is my bible. This file is very detailed, with complete search capability. I cannot give you that file for fear of legal implications, but you can install ActiveState Tcl to get it.

Comment: Thank you. Since I got a tcl prompts anyway I thought it is executing the script but somehow not printing the output of the commands. It makes sense now. However, I have another question. Are the the question mark syntax as you have written above, as well as seen on tcl manual pages something specific to Tcl? Where can I find some information on this representation syntax/style? Many thanks!

Comment: @Lavya The `?` indicate optional arguments to the command `tclsh`.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks! What is the difference in the three different kinds of `?`s used in the above answer? ( 1.: `?-encoding` 2.: `name?` 3.: `?fileName` )

Comment: @Lavya The arguments `-encoding name` are optional, but if you use `-encoding`, then the next argument will be interpreted as the encoding name, even if you put a file name there. So, if you use the `-encoding` argument, you have to use a name. It's the same for the `fileName` and `arg`, except that with `...` it means you can use as many arguments as required, and you can use none as well.

Comment: @Hai THanks. I got the guide by a little bit of googling.